# How to train Abbyy OCR ( command line version )

Tags: ocr, abbyy

We are scanning PDF files and we are not getting a date as correctly as we want.

Is there any way to train abbyy OCR like we do with [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract)?

Comment: What product and version of ABBYY technology?